# How to get list of Tweets by hash tag that are more than 7 days old

Tags: twitter

I am using this URL `http://search.twitter.com/search.json` to grab tweets with the hash tag `#SameHashTag`.   The feed only returns items within the past week.  Twitter explains why here:

`https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#8650`

I really need to get the last 10 tweets, regardless of when they were created.  What is the alternative?

**Note** I read about user_timeline, but that seems to be based on user instead of hashtag.  I read about list_timeline, but that seems to pull tweets from a defined list of users instead of hashtag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get old tweets from Search API. If your hashtag doesn't change you could search it and save results every day and build your own history.